# How to display a database table data that is automatically updating ( no need to refresh) using codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a queue management system for a school project and I want to display the queue list using database table and I want it to update live without refreshing the web. How to display a database table data that is automatically updating ( no need to refresh) using Codeigniter? I'm trying to make a queue management system and I want to display the queue list using database table and I want it to update live without refreshing the web. Someone advice me to use Ajax but I don't know how to use it yet. Please help me I need some detailed explanation or reference code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is not really appropriate for SO, as it is very broad and answers will be opinion-based. SO is not a forum, it is for specific problems about programming, usually with some code involved. Please have a look at the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) guides for more info. Try searching eg for "real time codeigniter" for some tips; once you have some code, if you're having trouble, come to SO for help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On page load please fetch all the data from the database. And also store the last inserted id in the hidden field and then run ajax from last updated id to the all available ids.

Here is the ajax that you can use

```
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '/user/getData',
       crossDomain: true,
       beforeSend: function() {

       },
       success: function(res) {
            $('#tablerow').append(res);

       }
    });
```

in the getData function you can simple send back the new rows created in the table row format and append them to the body of the table

Comment: Why assume the OP uses, can use or even desires to use jQuery?